# Wordpress media upload in front-end blocked by admin redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, editor, media

I'm using wp-editor to let users write text & upload media.

I added a script that prevents users from going to the back-end if they're not logged as admin.

This is the script :

```
function yproject_admin_init() {
   if (! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' )) {
     wp_redirect(site_url());
     exit();
   }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'yproject_admin_init' );
```

The problem is: with non-admin users, when they try to upload files, the file seems to upload but at the end, the get the message : "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

If I delete the "redirect" and "exit" lines, it works fine (but obviously, the user access the admin side).

Which test could I add to prevent this?

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767629/wordpress-an-error-occurred-in-the-upload

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had found this solution but it doesn't work with my website.

Answer (score 0):

Im grateful to "Emilien" who posted the question at the top of this page over 10 years ago(!), because it led us to see that it was the admin redirect function in our functions.php that was preventing nonAdmin users from getting to the media library, not necessarily their roll capabilities.  Then "manishie" above posted the link (see his note above for the link) to another post which actually solved our problem. I'm posting this solution in both places. So, based on the basic solution provided in the other post by "HWD", here is the rewrite of our nonAdminRedirect() function in functions.php. (WordPress 6.4.2 as of this writing.)

```
function nonAdminRedirect() {
  // how to see the $_SERVER[] data when accessing media lib
  // rprint2f("_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = ", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  // rprint2f("_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = ", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  // rprint2f() is our own print_r() print to file function, feel free to request

  if( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-login.php' ){
    return true; // allow users to login

  } else if ( 
   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'   || // Media Library call
   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/async-upload.php' || // "Upload Image" clicked
   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == '/wp-admin/post.php')           // "Edit Image" clicked
   {   
    $roles_array = ['administrator', 'gw-contributor'];
    // Check if the user is one of the specified roles
    $user_has_allowed_role = false;
    foreach ($roles_array as $allowed_role) {
      if (in_array($allowed_role, $current_user->roles)) {
        $user_has_allowed_role = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if ($user_has_allowed_role) {
      return true;
    } else {
      wp_safe_redirect(site_url());
      exit;
    }

  } else { 
    // otherwise this is not-a-login && not-an-ajax-call
    if(current_user_can('administrator') != 'administrator'){
    // Non-admin access to dashboard or other admin
      wp_safe_redirect(site_url());
      exit;
    } 
  }
}
add_action( 'login_form_login', 'nonAdminRedirect' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'nonAdminRedirect', 1 );
```

Final note: These are the capabilities we assign in a special roll we created called "gw-contributor" to add/edit/delete a special post type "greatworkers": [edit_greatworkers, publish_greatworkers, delete_greatworkers, read, upload_files, edit_files, edit_posts, delete_posts].  Once inside the media library, "edit_posts" is required for the "Edit Image" link to work and "delete_posts" is required for the "Delete Permanently" link.