# Uploadify broblem with over 10MB files

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

recently I downloaded the new uploadify plugin for multiple file uploads. It was perfect until i tried to upload a movie about 700MB. After some searching i found than i can't upload any file over 10MB.

Here is my jquery script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php $timestamp = time();?>
    $(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'formData'     : {
                'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
                'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
            },
            'auto'     : false,
            'progressData' : 'speed',
            'buttonText' : 'Choose files...',
            'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',

        });
    });
</script>
```

Please help !!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Maximum Total Upload Size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727736/php-maximum-total-upload-size)

Answer (score 0):

**Changing the limit on Uploadify**

Set the size limit!

```
'sizeLimit':1024*1024*1024*2 //2GB
```

Altogether now...

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'formData'     : {
            'timestamp' : '<?php echo $timestamp;?>',
            'token'     : '<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>'
        },
        'auto'     : false,
        'progressData' : 'speed',
        'buttonText' : 'Choose files...',
        'sizeLimit': 1024*1024*1024*2,
        'swf'      : 'uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',

    });
});
```

You may likely increase the size limit because straight 700MB might not be enough for your image.  If it doesn't work, do 800MB

**EDIT** I revised the code to use 2G file size limit instead.

**Changing it in PHP**

Go to your php.ini file and set the following parameters:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2047M
post_max_size = 2047M
```

**PHP is likely your problem because 10MB is the default hard limit**

Comment: pointless to modify the JS code if php's own size limit is too low.

Comment: When i am trying to upload a movie bigger than 10MB it;s shows that all thinks gone perfect but then when i see the upload file there is nothing there

Comment: i change the size limit from php.ini

Comment: Good!  Then set `upload_max_filesize = 700M` AND make sure `post_max_size` is also big enough in php.ini.

Comment: i have this things to 2GB

Comment: I'll change the answer to accomodate

Comment: yes i have change the php.ini like you said but still not working

Comment: Try `2047M` instead of `2G`, I've never actually tested with using the letter "G"

Comment: well i don't know if the php.ini has the problem i think the uplodify has problem

Comment: i'm trying to make a file sharing website and this is very important for me so if anyone knows something please help

Comment: Maybe try: `sizeLimit: '2GB'` or `sizeLimit: '2047MB'`?  Otherwise, no clue... :/