# Increasing Upload_Max_Filesize limit

Tags: php, wordpress, configuration, upload

I am facing a little problem with increasing the Upload_Max_Filesize limit on a clients server. The Upload_Max_Filesize is set to 2M and I need to increase it to at least 10M. There's no php.ini file currently present inside any of the folders albeit I tried creating a php.ini file and then uploaded it to the root folder of the website but that didn't work. I also edited the .htaccess file by putting these two lines inside it but, sadly, that didn't work either:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

I have access to the cPanel but it's mentioned inside the PHP Configuration page that:

```
These PHP configuration settings are customizable by the server administrator. They are listed for reference only.
```

Please let me know if there's any other way through which I can increase the limit of Upload_Max_Filesize.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload max size in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263480/upload-max-size-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727736/php-maximum-total-upload-size/727759#727759

Comment: Assuming this is a *nix OS:  did you try executing 'updatedb' and then 'locate php.ini'?  Also, not sure if the output of 'phpinfo();' shows the location but have you tried that yet as well?

Comment: ask your host,if its a 'cheap' one you probably dont have the option

Comment: If it says they're only customizable by the server administrator, then they probably are only customizable by the server administrator and you should be contacting him/her to maybe get the values changed for your site. If you are that server administrator, find your php.ini

Comment: I think you are putting entries to wrong php.ini. Create a phpinfo in your public_html and see what is the "Loaded configuration" in the top of info page. If that shows a location where not inside the corresponding home folder, Copy that php.ini to your home folder and make changes or make changes to the entries in the actual php.ini which has shown to you in the info page. Other wise the php.ini page can be located by this command. php --ini

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact your host to increase your upload size. I've successfully done it from 5mb to 20mb. You just need to ask.

Comment: as its all ready been stated several times in the comments, this is not much of an answer.